# How to use teamlink on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, wine

Teamlink is a video conferencing software that we have to use for online classes. It's the software that seems to work fine even in low connectivity areas. But it is not compatible with Ubuntu or Linux.

I have it on my phone. But it's difficult to attend a class on a phone. I need a bigger screen. I have tired screen casting to my laptop but the quality is really low.

Comment: Is it compatible with windows?

Comment: Yes, it is.....

Answer (score 0):

TeamLink is now compatible with Linux (`.AppImage`). You can download it from https://www.teamlink.co/download.html